# Click two buttons sequentially with TouchActions

Tags: android, ruby, cucumber, appium

I am newbie using Appium. 
My feature flow is using android camera UI like this:
[image: Android emulator camera UI]

So after i take photo, there is "check button" beside "shutter button". The problem is, after appium check element in shutter button and doing tap action on it, it can't locate next element, it means "check button". My script just like this:

> Then ("I click shutter camera button and confirm it") do
>
> action_one = Appium::TouchAction.new.tap(x: 531.5, y: 1609.6, count: 1).tap(x: 967.7, y: 1626.0, count: 1)
>
> action_one.perform
>
> end

How to perform TouchAction in two different buttons sequentially?

Answer (score 2):

What error are you getting exactly?

Try adding waitAction() between two tap actions:
action_one = Appium::TouchAction.new.tap(x: 531.5, y: 1609.6, count: 1).waitAction().tap(x: 967.7, y: 1626.0, count: 1)

Answer (score 0):

Tapping on coordintates are not recommened approach as it might give you inconsistent results.
Better way is to find element id or Xpath of the element on which you want to click.

You can use [Appium Desktop](https://automationlab0000.wordpress.com/2018/12/31/appium-desktop-for-locating-elements/) to find the xpath or Element id for the requested element